# issues running a face_recogition file using editors and cmd

Tags: python, face-recognition

When I run the code below in jupyter, it is excellent, I get the results I want.

```
real = fr.load_image_file("image.jpg")
unknown = fr.load_image_file("image2.jpg")

# encodings
real_encoding = fr.face_encodings(real)[0]
unk = fr.face_encodings(unknown)[0]

result = fr.compare_faces([real_encoding], unk)

print(result)
```

but when I copy and paste the same code to an editor(atom the one I am using), and then run it using command prompt, I get an error as shown below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "face_recognizer.py", line 13, in <module>
    real_encoding = fr.face_encodings(real)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I activated the environment in which I was running the cmd.

Can someone advise me where I maybe going wrong?

Comment: Can you share image1 and image2 ?
These errors occurs sometimes because there is no face in your images or faces cannot be found !

Answer (score 0):

There was no face captured in the photo.
That is why it throws an exception.